# Fo-Dicom, how I get all tags values?

Tags: tags, fo-dicom

Does anyone knows how to get all tags values using Fo-Dicom?

I'm trying to display all tags in a window at once but I can't find a method to traverse through every tag!

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To traverse a DICOM dataset in *fo-dicom*, there is an interface `IDicomDatasetWalker` and a helper class `DicomDatasetWalker`, both defined in [this](https://github.com/rcd/fo-dicom/blob/master/DICOM/DicomDatasetWalker.cs) source file. You should create your custom dataset walker by implementing the `IDicomDatasetWalker` interface.

A good starter example of such an implementation is given in the *DICOM Dump* application, as a private class inside the [MainForm](https://github.com/rcd/fo-dicom/blob/master/Tools/DICOM%20Dump/MainForm.cs) class.

Comment: Thanks! I looked into the example and implemented it in my project. Thanks again